# Could not recognize my android device on mac

Tags: android, macos, connection, usb

I am trying to connect my android device on mac to test application I developed.
First I installed USB driver, then I activated in my phone the developer option by tapping on Build Number and then tick USB debugging option.
Once I did all those steps when I connect my android mobile, my Mac still not recognize my device.
Any idea to solve it?

Comment: Have you downloaded `Android drivers` ?

Comment: I have installed Google USB driver and USB driver for my mobile

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I after few research and testing of existing solutions, I found mine, my issue was released while I have installed [Android file Transfer for Mac](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/)

Comment: This is a Google tool that works with Android 3.0 and above.

Comment: I installed the latest version (replace the previous version) of AFT and it started working.

Answer (score 68):

Maybe it's your USB cable, try another one.

There are two types of USB cables:

- for supplying power only
- for supplying power and data

Answer (score 21):

I experienced the same problem with a Moto X and my Macbook Pro. I tried many of the suggestions (installed Android File Transfer, tried different usb ports on my computer, `Settings` => `Storage` => `USB computer connection` => toggled between MTP and PTP, etc.).  None of these other recommendations helped.

**It finally worked when I tried a different micro-usb cable**.

Bizarre. You definitely want to first enable `Developer Options` first by going to `Settings` => `About Phone` => tapping `Build number` 7 times to display `Developer Options`. From there, you want to enable `USB debugging`.

Comment: I should also add that for me, the only thing that works, was using the USB port on my display that is connected through USB-c to my mac. Seems like the multi connectivity of these USB-C ports are not very great yet on macs.

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution to be helpful to resolve this problem

1. Connect your Android to your Mac via USB.
2. Unlock your Android's screen. ...
3. **Swipe down to open the Android Notification Panel.**
4. **Tap the USB option in the Notification Panel.
   Tap "File transfer" or "MTP."**
5. Click the Go menu and select "Applications."
6. Double-click "Android File Transfer."

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250023078

Comment: This one worked for me. I had to install "Android file transfer" from the internet and then it was all good after reconnecting the phone.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add my experience here. I had a similar problem with my mac book pro and my Google Pixel 1 device. For me when running `adb devices` locally, I was no longer showing my device on the list. I would see any emulators I had running, but not my physical device.

My solution and steps:

- Go to the "Settings App"
- Go to "Developer Options"
- Revoke USB debugging Authorizations
- Toggle Developer Options off / on

My device then prompted me to allow debugging from my computer and everything continued to work as expected. `adb devices` resulted in showing my connected device.

Hopefully, this will help someone else if the above does not.

Comment: Revoking USB debugging authorizations helped

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. The only solution was to reboot my computer. Then it started working again.

Comment: The universal solution for all computer problems lol :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have debugging by usb enable on your device.

It is an option inside "Developer options"

Answer (score 1):

I've recently (2018) started to have this issue, and have found the only way to get my device connected is to use a USB hub. I have not been able to track down a root cause but will edit this answer if I can find a solution rather than a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I connected my Android deceive with my mac:

1) If you use `Android studio`, you may update to latest version of `1.0.2` or `1.1 preview`, because lower version have some problem with ADB connection.

2) You may restart your IDE once again.

3) You may go to `settings` -- `storage` -- three docs on the right up corner -- `USB computer connection` -- enable `MTP`

Answer (score 0):

I have an HTC U11 and a MacBook Pro (2017). It used to work most of the time, but I experienced issues with it once or twice. Then a restart of the Mac solved the problem.
Recently I was not able to USB debug. `adb devices` gave nothing, even though my phone said I'm USB debugging (even asked if I wanted to).

After trying many things the solution was to connect my phone and run HTC Sync Manager (I also had to update it). Then it magically started to woek.

I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

check your android sdk tools, install your sdk-plateform-tools package.then it is ok

Answer (score 0):

For me what fixed the problem is

1. i clicked on the notification "USB for file transfer" in the
   notification panel on the phone
2. Clicked on "Transferring images"
3. Than I clicked on "Transferring files / Android Auto" and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If your device was previously authorized/working but no longer, I found that I can get the Android device to trigger the prompt to authorize the Mac again by ***changing the mode of the USB connection to USB tethering***

[image: Notification in tray]

Tap  that to go to the USB settings (or go there directly from the Android settings), and then select "USB tethering"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What helped me finally connect was going to Settings -> Developer Options -> Turn on USB Debugging.